# uncaughtException: missing packet mqtt nodejs

Tags: android, node.js, mqtt, mosquitto

I am using node module mqtt and mosquitto installed on my ubuntu machine in one of chatApplication. Some time i got error on server i.e of missing packet. As i google it i found that this error occurred when there is no client id found or if we are trying to connect the client which is already connected.

We are using android at client side and

> setting QOS level :2
>
> cleanSession :false

What we are doing here in server side we have some users which are friend of other so we are making client object for each users as they are made friends of each other from our logic.Via there client id then connect them and then subscribing them after that we disconnect the client. So that when user not making connection from client side at very first time we received the message because we subscribed the channel at once already in server side. And that was running well we got messages as client is not connected at very first time.
There is one more condition that is when client refresh the list than again we are repeating the server side code as i defined above

> making client
>
> connect them
>
> and than subscribe the channel
>
> than disconnnect

The code for subscribing connecting and disconnecting client is:-

```
  var client = mqtt.connect(configurationHolder.config.mqttUrl, {
        clientId: from_user.toString(),
        clean: false
    });
        
    client.on('connect', function () {
        console.log("into connect function.....");
        //Logger.log("into client client ******", subscribe_topic);
        var chanelobj = {};
        chanelobj[subscribe_topic] = 2;
        client.subscribe(chanelobj, function (err, granted) {
            if (err)
                Logger.log("error while subscribing..", err);
            else if (granted)
                console.log("granted...", granted);
            client.end();
        });
    //    Logger.info("chanel subscribe  ", subscribe_topic);
    });
```

But sometime we get the missing packet exception in server side and i.e

```
"stack": [
    "Error: missing packet",
    "    at Store.get (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/mqtt/lib/store.js:92:8)",
    "    at MqttClient._handlePubrel (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:858:22)",
    "    at MqttClient._handlePacket (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:279:12)",
    "    at process (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:226:12)",
    "    at MqttClient._handlePacket (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:283:7)",
    "    at process (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:226:12)",
    "    at Writable.writable._write (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:236:5)",
    "    at doWrite (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:237:10)",
    "    at writeOrBuffer (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:227:5)",
    "    at Writable.write (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:194:11)",
    "    at write (_stream_readable.js:583:24)",
    "    at flow (_stream_readable.js:592:7)",
    "    at Socket.pipeOnReadable (_stream_readable.js:624:5)",
    "    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)",
    "    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)",
    "    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)",
    "    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)",
    "    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)",
    "    at TCP.onread (net.js:526:21)"
  ],
  "level": "error",
  "message": "uncaughtException: missing packet"
}
```

And also getting error at client side i.e:-

> subscribe failConnection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException

I am not able to find where is the actual problem at client side or server side . At server side there is issue in disconnecting client or at client side. Please help me to get out from this situation . Also let me know how to debug this problem.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Ya i am also facing the same problem . Please help me too

Comment: All clients must have unique client ids. Also are you making multiple client connections from the same device?

Comment: @hardillb Thanks for your response, We are making single connection for one client with unique ids as i described above. We are first making connection in server side and close that before giving to the mobile side i.e first time subscription we are doing from server side after that mobile side we are connecting clients only once via unique id